# Oracle Apex 5.1 Interactive Grid in Sub Region Disappearing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I've got 2 interactive grid sub regions on a page and after clicking around on the page (about 10/12 clicks or so), the second interactive grid disappears - no errors showing in console.

The workaround that we've found is to not put the interactive grids into sub regions but that in turn doesn't make the app look great - due to our own theme.

Has anyone experienced this or knows how to keep the grids in sub regions without disappearing?

Comment: Haven't seen this myself; but I'd look at the layout, perhaps see if the first IG is obscuring the second after a refresh? Try using a different template for the sub regions? Can you reproduce the effect on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. One of our devs that was working on it has said that it's some custom javascript for highlighting on the IG that appears to be causing the issue.